# Keyboard on HP notebook stops working under kernel 5.4.0-45-generic

Tags: boot, kernel, keyboard

The built-in keyboard on my "HP Pavilion 11 x360 PC" stops working in the graphical login under kernel 5.4.0-45-generic on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa).  Booting to the previous kernel (5.4.0-42-generic) works fine.  Booting back to 5.4.0-45 breaks it again. I tried running "sudo update-initramfs -u" and "sudo update-grub".  An external USB keyboard works under both kernels, but this defeats the purpose of a notebook computer.

Comment: I have the same problem (my hp is the x360 11 n010-nv). I reinstalled Ubuntu, Xubuntu and even Linux Mint (the moment I upgraded the kernel I got the same problem).

Comment: Same problem here, same PC. I hoped that yesterday's update to 5.4.0-47 would solve it, but same issue. I have keyboard input only to unlock LUKS; after that keyboard is completely dead. Xserver-xorg-input-all update had no effect (was already installed and at latest version). I'm just manually booting into the -42 kernel for now.

Comment: Same issue with an Acer EX2509-C7WT.  I notice apt is now threatening to autoremove kernel 5.4.0-42-generic.

Comment: Problem still occurring with 5.4.0-48-generic.

Comment: I found a simple workaround and possible root of problem: here is [my question with answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20)

Comment: I have the same problem with my wireless keyboard and mouse from logitech in Ubuntu. With kernel 5.0.0-37 it was working, since kernel 5.3.0-26 it is not working anymore. Seems to be the still unsolved bug on: <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1863455>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my laptop's keyboard screwed up since kernel 5.4.0-47 till 5.8.0-20?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-is-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20)

Comment: The problem was still there in 5.4.0-52-generic and 5.4.0-53-generic, but is fixed in 5.4.0-58-generic.  I haven't tested the intervening 5.4.0-56-generic.

Comment: Thank you.  I no longer have the problem on 5.4.0-58-generic.  I no longer had it on 5.4.0-56-generic, but 5.4.0-56-generic was a "skip" release, since it had a serious data integrity bug.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug already https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894017

As of 6/9/2020 it has been confirmed but it is unassigned.

A [possible workaround](https://www.mail-a.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg420371.html) is Ctrl+Alt+F3 on a *external keyboard*.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found success by installing and booting to the **5.4.18-050418-generic** kernel.

Since 5.4 is a longterm support version and ~.18 is only a few point releases below the current stable kernel, I'm happy sticking with this finally. A variety of other kernel versions I tested (both higher and lower) seemed not to recognize the keyboard input. So although it seems odd, it seems specifically kernels 5.4.0-42, kernel 5.4.18, and most of the 4.~ series kernels work.

I used "[Mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline)" to install the kernel, searching for 5.4.18 and installing it. One more thing: I had to disable Secure Boot to boot to kernels installed this way.

Comment: Update: the issue itself seems fixed at least as of 5.10

Answer (score 0):

I finally had "success" with my current kernel version 5.4.0-58.
This shows the ***keyring not unlocked*** first in white  on a black screen background on my laptop screen (my hp is the **x360 11 n010-nv**) and then in white  on a black screen background on my external monitor (**HP Z24**).  Waiting a little longer, both the screens change to display to usual theme picture with the ***keyring not unlocked*** on my external monitor as usual.
I can enter my password on the white ***keyring not unlocked*** on my external monitor with the black screen background but ubuntu does NOT display the ******, nor respond until the theme picture appears with the keyring unlocked and ready to go on my external monitor.

I hope this helps other HP X360  11 users !