# Built in mouse and keyboard on HP notebook stop working

Tags: boot, 20.04, keyboard, mouse, freeze

Running Ubuntu on an HP notebook. Installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS, later upgraded to 20.04. I am having trouble with the built-in mouse and keyboard. After booting, they work for some time, then stop working[freeze], like maybe a few minutes later. Restarting restarts the problem haha.External keyboard and mouse do work though.
(An interesting fact is that if you press the Caps Lock key during this period of time, it won't shut off lol).
Upgraded kernel to 5.10.0-051000-generic, didn't help. Also found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290369/1193730), my issue is similair. Typed the command, it gave out a 10. Tried the proposed fix, didn't help.

Is there a way to fix this? I am pretty new to this,so please consider that when answering.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get this kernel from? 5.10.0-051000-generic

Comment: I installed it from the official site. Earlier versions were also tried.

Comment: Linux Kernel 4.15
For Ubuntu 18.04, for example, this is the Linux Kernel 4.15. Security updates are provided for this kernel version for a period of five years.23 Jul 2020 For 18.04 this the kernel so I do not know where you got the one you are trying to use.

Comment: Yep, I had that version before upgrading the kernel. The problem was exactly the same.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 ships with 5.4 kernel, which brings support for Intel's Comet Lake chips as well as the beginning of Tiger Lake support. If you keep track of the kernels, you might be disappointed, since the baked-in support for Wireguard in the kernel doesn't come until 5.6.4 May 2020

Comment: I am dissapointed. A deviation of +-.11 is is still not so bad though. So I try setting it to 4.15?

Comment: You might want to on April 22 update to 21.04 when it comes out.

Comment: Huh. Ok I guess. So this is an issue in the kernel?

Comment: FYI I used https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: Just because the ppa has a kernel does not mean it is the one for your version any way good luck.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure if issue is kernel.  You said that keyboard and touch pad works for a bit after Ubuntu loads.  Past problem with kernel was that keyboard would not work with Ubuntu, only bios/grub, could not even log in.  20.04 is using 5.4 or 5.8 kernels(HWE)

Comment: As shown in the hyperlink[although I don't know how trustworthy the source is], this issue may be caused by other things.