# I Just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 and my keyboard doesn't work

Tags: xorg, input

As I said, my keyboard doesn't work.
I did secure boot>root console>sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all.
It worked but when I restart, gone again.
I'm having really serious problems with the xorg input.
How can I fix this FOREVER?

Comment: Does anything else revert after a reboot? Conversely, does everything else that you do persist after a reboot?

Comment: no, It doesn't. I reboot, try to login but my keyboard doesn't work suddenly. I really love Linux but it made me colder for it.

Comment: My documents and everything are persist. Nothing reverts

Comment: There is a bug starting in kernel 5.4.0-44 that stops some laptop keyboards from working.  If you have this bug, only fix right now is to use an external keyboard/mouse.  Don't know if you have access to kernel 5.4.0-42, last known to work.

Comment: Desktop or Server installation? Laptop or Desktop computer? Internal or external keyboard... and what type... USB/other? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer or motherboard. You may have to do this from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB if you can't use your current Ubuntu installation. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: thanks! btw I have 5.4.0-48-generic. I thought It would be helpful to reporting issue.

Comment: It's a desktop. I use Laptop. And Internal keyboard

Comment: I set it up to my internal hard drive

Comment: @heynnema I wrote code that you want. V2.10 and It's Acer Aspire

Comment: searching for it's model

Comment: @heynnema It's Acer V3-551G

Comment: I tried to boot with 5.4.0-42-generic instead of 5.4.0-48-generic. And It worked! Thanks for helping!

Comment: Be sure to check your updates carefully, since they will try to clean/remove older kernels, only keeping two or three of the most recent.  An external keyboard/mouse might be handy to have, till bug is fixed.

Comment: @crip659 looks like a BIOS update fixed this problem. I find that a lot with 20.04.

Comment: Will check with my Acer after, but think bios is up to date.  Does not seem to affect the Dell I am using right now.

Comment: @heynnema  unfortunately mine is already newest bios version.   If you have any others ideas for this bug(is listed as bug) I would not mine hearing of it.  A few others have already asked about this.

Comment: @crip659 Do you have a link to the bug report?

Comment: @heynnema   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894017  found from this question  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271845/keyboard-on-hp-notebook-stops-working-under-kernel-5-4-0-45-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

Acer Aspire V3-551G

You have BIOS 2.10.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 2.14, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support-product/4099?b=1).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.